# Как найти ближайшие поликлиники, детские сады, парки и т.п. в yandex карты api?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-places-api

Есть ли возможность в API искать по атрибутам мест(организаций)? (https://yandex.ru/support/nmaps/cat_organizations_rul2.html)

Comment: Геокодер позволяет искать ближайшие станции метро - есть пример. А есть ли аналогичные методы в аpi, которые не станции метро, а найдут ближайшие детсады например?

Answer (score 1):

Есть [API Поиска по организациям (Геопоиска)](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geosearch/?from=SO), который позволяет искать адреса и организации на карте.

Искать можно по названию организации, номеру телефона или названию услуг. [Подробнее в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/geosearch/examples/geosearch_examples-docpage/?from=SO#business)

Comment: Спасибо большое за содержательный ответ!  Есть ли возможность через данное API определить, есть ли рядом река (водоем) и кратчайшее расстояние до него?

Comment: Реки тоже можно искать через API по названию, просто определить, что на расстоянии менее Х есть водоем скорее всего не получится